# Java Buy method

Tags: java, casting

This is my home work.
I am trying to write a method 'buy' that allows some shares of the stock to be bought at a given price. The method takes two arguments: a number of shares as an int, and a price per share as a double. 
For example:

```
Stock myStock = new Stock("FCS");
myStock.buy(20, 3.50); // buys 20 shares at $3.50
// myStock now has 20 shares at total cost $70.00
myStock.buy(10, 2.00); // buys 10 shares at $2.00
// myStock now has 30 shares at total cost $90.00
```

My Code :

```
public static void buy(int numBuyShares, double priceBuyShares )
{
    double tempTotalCost = ((double)numBuyShares * priceBuyShares);
```

1. How do I write a proper code if I want to multiply Integer by Double? Am I doing this the right way?
2. I would like to accumulate the cost and shares, so how do I write this? Because I need to use the shares and cost for a `sell` method.

Thank you all . Now I need to write a method sell that allows some shares of the stock to be sold at a given price. The method takes two arguments: a number of shares as an int, and a price per share as a double. The method returns a boolean value to indicate whether the sale was successful. For example:

```
 // myStock now has 30 shares at total cost $90.00
boolean success = myStock.sell(5, 4.00);
// sells 5 shares at $4.00 successfully
// myStock now has 25 shares at total cost $70.00
success = myStock.sell(2, 5.00);
// sells 2 shares at $5.00 successfully
// myStock now has 23 shares at total cost $60.00
```

1.) How do i use the previous shares to minus of the new price and the shares method?

Comment: Thanks. I am a newbie here.

Comment: Is the use of `double` for the price part of the assignment? Because it's really not ideal...

Comment: First thing I noticed: check your variable names. numBuyShares != numShares, priceBuyShares != priceShares

Comment: yes, the double price is part of the assignment.

Comment: `double` works as a representation of integers [up to 2^52](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FloatingPoint) and most integer math but you may run into ugly rounding errors: [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Comment: Actually , I am doing Multi Thread Java Code. I am writing Stocks program. I need to have buy , sell , profit method. First Buy stock, sell stock , finally profit.

Comment: Ya, i think it is ugly to do such code.

Answer (score 0):

1. There no need for explicit casting of `numShares` to double. The implicit auto-boxing will take care of it, as there's already double variable `priceShares` - double arithmetic will be used.
2. To save the number and price of your stock, you will have to use some kind of structure. I am thinking `HashMap` perhaps. But it's really not good to use `double` as a key there so, I would create some Stock class. So the key of your `HashMap` can the `Stock` object containing price and the int is the number of said stocks in you possession.

   `HashMap<Stock, int> stocks = new HashMap<Stock, int>();`

Comment: Can I write this in my Stock classs :private Queue<Stock> StockList = new LinkedList<Stock>();
And can I write this code my in my buy method ?                     Stock newStock = new Stocks(numBuyShares,priceBuyShares);
StockList.add(newStock);

Comment: well i think it would be better to use a map because you might want to buy 2 shares, then decide to buy 4 more. In a map you will try it already contains the stock you're buying, if it does then just increase the count in your map.

Answer (score 0):

1. That way of multiplying a double and an integer will work fine.
2. To accumulate total shares you need a variable in the Stock class to keep track. For example:

   ```
   public class Stock{
       private int noOfShares = 0;
   }
   ```

   Then in the buy method you need to add a line to add the number of shares just bought to it:

   ```
   noOfShares += numBuyShares;
   ```

   Following encapsulation principles, to access this variable from outside the class, you will need a get method, ie:

   ```
   public int getNoOfShares(){
       return noOfShares;
   }
   ```

Comment: Same apply for the total cost?

Comment: Yes, only difference is totalCost will be a double.